Diagnostic floats on default keymaps
im wondering why the diagnostic floats dont pop when I goto_prev or goto_next using the default keymaps. This only works with I explicitly set:
vim.keymap.set('n', '[d', vim.diagnostic.goto_prev)
vim.keymap.set('n', ']d', vim.diagnostic.goto_next)


Floats are disabled on default keymappings: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/pull/16230
